# How to get the selected index of a RadioGroup in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-group

Is there an easy way to get the selected index of a RadioGroup in Android or do I have to use OnCheckedChangeListener to listen for changes and have something that holds the last index selected?

example xml:

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/group1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio1" android:text="option 1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2" android:text="option 2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio3" android:text="option 3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio4" android:text="option 4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio5" android:text="option 5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RadioGroup>
```

if a user selects `option 3` I want to get the index, 2.

Answer (score 517, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int idx = radioButtonGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```

If the `RadioGroup` contains other Views (like a `TextView`) then the `indexOfChild()` method will return wrong index.

To get the selected `RadioButton` text on the `RadioGroup`:

```
 RadioButton r = (RadioButton) radioButtonGroup.getChildAt(idx);
 String selectedtext = r.getText().toString();
```

Comment: But what if those buttons do not have their `android:id` attributes set?

Comment: @BP i have same doubt in accessing radio buttons when none of the parent or the radio buttons id is set.

Comment: @neuront As long as you do radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID) it'll work. RadioGroup does set 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on as view's IDs, so if you do search for them within it's context, it'll work

Comment: This not working if default (and untouched by User) RadioButton is setted.

Comment: @NinjaCoding If you made the same mistake as me, you have to set the default (initial) radio button by calling radioGroup.check(selectedRadioButton.id), not radioButton.setChecked(true).

Answer (score 117):

This should work,

```
int index = myRadioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
```

Comment: Use getActivity().findViewById() if you are using in the Fragment.

Answer (score 56):

You could have a reference to the radio group and use `getCheckedRadioButtonId ()` to get the checked radio button id. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29)

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
```

Then when you need to get the selected radio option.

```
int checkedRadioButtonId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
if (checkedRadioButtonId == -1) {
    // No item selected
}
else{
    if (checkedRadioButtonId == R.id.radio_button1) {
        // Do something with the button
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this is the id of the checked radio button, but what about the index of the radio button in the radio group?

Comment: i can get the id, i want the index, they are different.

Comment: what do you mean by index? is it in a list view?

Comment: if i have 5 radiobuttons in the radiogroup, and the user selects the 3rd one i want to get 2, the index of the selected radiobutton in the radiogroup.  this is not a listview.

Comment: just to clarify if the user selects the 3rd button you want to get the 2nd one? radio groups and buttons do not have indexes.

Comment: no, the index of the 3rd button is 2, zero based indexing.  the first radio button has an index of 0, second is 1, third 2, etc...  What you're saying is there's no good way to get the index, that's a valid answer too.

Comment: You could put the RadioButton in an array list and then run a search for the id and convert that into an index

Comment: Terrible idea if you have 20+ items.

Answer (score 29):

try this

```
        RadioGroup  group= (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(i);
                int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is works! But i can't understand why we need use this "radioButton" View..

Answer (score 10):

You can either use OnCheckedChangeListener or can use [getCheckedRadioButtonId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29)

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

Answer (score 6):

//use to get the id of selected item

```
int selectedID = myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

//get the view of the selected item

```
View selectedView = (View)findViewById( selectedID);
```

Answer (score 6):

It worked perfectly for me in this way:

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
    String selectedtext = (String) radioButton.getText();
```

Answer (score 5):

All you need is to set values first to your RadioButton, for example:

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton);      
radioButton.setId(1);        //some int value
```

and then whenever this spacific radioButton will be chosen you can pull its value by the Id you gave it with

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);                     
int whichIndex = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); //of course the radioButton
                                                       //should be inside the "radioGroup"
                                                       //in the XML
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

```
radioSexGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

  btnDisplay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

  btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        int selectedId=radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioSexButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,radioSexButton.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

> Kotlin:

```
val selectedIndex = radioButtonGroup?.indexOfChild(
  radioButtonGroup?.findViewById(
    radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but here is a simplification of @Tarek360's Kotlin answer that caters for `RadioGroup`s that might contain non-RadioButtons:

```
    val RadioGroup.checkedIndex: Int
        get() = children
            .filter { it is RadioButton }
            .indexOfFirst { it.id == checkedRadioButtonId }
```

If you're `RadioFroup` definitely only has `RadioButton`s then this can be a simple as:

```
    private val RadioGroup.checkedIndex = 
        children.indexOfFirst { it.id == checkedRadioButtonId }
```

Then you don't have the overhead of `findViewById`.

Comment: I posted this question 9 years ago and answers are still coming in.  Have my upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 int index_selected = radio_grp.indexOfChild(radio_grp
                .findViewById(radio_grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
```

Answer (score 2):

just use this:

```
    int index = 2;
    boolean option3Checked = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == radioGroup.getChildAt(2).getId();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **Kotlin** extension to get the **correct position even if** your group contains a TextView or any non-RadioButton.

```
fun RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonPosition(): Int {
    val radioButtonId = checkedRadioButtonId
    return children.filter { it is RadioButton }
        .mapIndexed { index: Int, view: View ->
            index to view
        }.firstOrNull {
            it.second.id == radioButtonId
        }?.first ?: -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
findViewById
```

from the radio group .

Here it is sample :

```
((RadioButton)my_radio_group.findViewById(R.id.radiobtn_veg)).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply

-declare the radio group and a radio button out of onCreate method

```
private RadioGroup GrupName;
private RadioButton NameButton;
```

-set the view id in the onCreate method

```
GrupName = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupid);
```

-take the radiobutton id selected using

```
int id = GroupName.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

-use the id to match the buttonselected view

```
NameButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
```

-finally get the value of the radio button

```
String valueExpected = NameButton.getText().toString();
```

--- PS: IF YOU WANT AN INT VALUE, THEN YOU CAN CAST IT

```
int valueExpectedIn = Integer.parseInt(valueExpected);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,radioSexButton.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already assigned an id for each radio button. With a case block you can detect manually the selected radio button or with OnCheckedChangeListener you get it too.

xml:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rd_group_pick_reason"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ti_titel"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd_not_deliverable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/txt_not_deliverable"
            android:checked="true"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd_after_pack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/txt_after_pack"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
```

java:

```
final RadioGroup radioGroup = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rd_group_pick_reason);    
switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.rd_not_deliverable:
        // TODO
    break;
    case R.id.rd_after_pack:
        // TODO
    break;
}
```

or

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
    switch (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.rd_not_deliverable:
            System.out.println("not deliverable");
            break;
        case R.id.rd_after_pack:
            System.out.println("after pack");
            break;
    }
```