# to have values of radio buttons in on resume

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I have values of radio buttons stored in `resume` method, but when I try to register the values, I have `NO VALUE IS DETECTED`. The weird thing is that I see the radio button selected but the value is zero.
So, when i go to database i have a=0 and b=0 which means the radio buttons are not clicked,
when i click again on radio button and after that the button, i have the right values in database, what i am looking for is i don't have to click again on radio button.

```
    public class ActivityUn extends Activity {
        public void  ajouter(View v) {

      db.open();               
          db.insertMENAGE(a,b);                   
          db.close();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données Enregistrées",            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } 


   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_un);       

         Button bton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ajoutUn);
         bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

          @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                   ajouter(v);                                            }
         });

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

            // Check which radio button was clicked
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.rm_13_1:
                    if (checked)
                          a=1;
                        break;
                case R.id.rm_13_2:
                    if (checked)
                        a=2;
                        break;

                case R.id.rm_14_1:
                    if (checked)
                        b=1;

                    break;
                case R.id.rm_14_2:
                    if (checked)
                        b=2;
                       break;
                case R.id.rm_14_3:
                    if (checked)
                        b=3;
                    findViewById
                    break;
                case R.id.rm_14_4:
                    if (checked)
                        b=4;
                          break;
  }
}




@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs3 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
        MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs3.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("questionA", rm_13_1.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("questionB", rm_13_2.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("questionC", rm_14_1.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("questionD", rm_14_2.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("questionE", rm_14_3.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs3 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
        MODE_PRIVATE);
    rm_13_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_13_1);
    rm_13_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_13_2);
    rm_14_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_14_1);
    rm_14_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_14_2);
    rm_14_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_14_3);
    Boolean rm_13_1A = false;
    Boolean rm_13_2A = false;
    Boolean rm_14_1A = false;
    Boolean rm_14_2A = false;
    Boolean rm_14_3A = false;
    rm_13_1A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionA", false);
    rm_13_2A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionB", false);
    rm_14_1A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionC", false);
    rm_14_2A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionD", false);
    rm_14_3A = prefs3.getBoolean("questionE", false);
    rm_13_1.setChecked(rm_13_1A);
    rm_13_2.setChecked(rm_13_2A);
    rm_14_1.setChecked(rm_14_1A);
    rm_14_2.setChecked(rm_14_2A);
    rm_14_3.setChecked(rm_14_3A);
}
```

Here the xml :

```
      <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rm_13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background ="#FFF8DC"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rm_13_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="OUI" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rm_13_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.81"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="NON" />

</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qm_14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    style = "@style/question"
    android:text="14. Statut de l’enquêté (e) :"
    />

<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/rm_14"
android:layout_width="838dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
android:layout_weight="0.00"
android:background="#FFF8DC"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rm_14_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:text="Chef de ménage " />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rm_14_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:text="Epoux (se) " />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rm_14_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fils ou fille aîné (e) " />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rm_14_4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.29"
    android:text="Autre " />
```

Comment: i would be very grateful if someone has an idea about this, i spent days looking for solution but i didn't find one, help please !!!

Comment: Post the activity_un.xml layout.

Comment: OK, i will post it now.

Comment: @ GareginSargsyan : can you explain that ?!

Comment: IS THERE NO SOLUTION TO THIS PROBLEM, I FINISHED MY APPLICAION ALL I NEED IS TO RESOLVE THIS ISSUE, GIVE ME JUST A HINT AND I WILL DO THE REST..

Answer (score 1):

I see two mistake in your code.

first you have `rm_14_4` in your XML but i never seen in your code that initialized.

second both of bellow code refer to one Button please fix that:

```
rm_14_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_14_2);
rm_14_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rm_14_2);
```

you used RadioGroup so worked with:

```
int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440259/how-to-get-the-selected-index-of-a-radiogroup-in-android) and

Comment: thanks for responding, yes i already fix these two, the problem is that i have to click again on radio button to get the value, but i already stored in shared Preferences that, how to solve that !!

Comment: you mean when your app is resumed don't get value from shared preference?

Comment: yes, i see the radio button checked but when i click on button to register the value as specified in  onRadioButtonClicked i have 0 as a value, which means that the radio button is not clicked !!!

Comment: see My Edit, work with RadioGroup instead of RadioButton

Comment: thanks a lot for efforts, i hope it will works !

Comment: I'm glad to help, i will hope too

Answer (score 1):

Use `RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` and `RadioGroup.check()` instead of calling `RadioButton.isChecked()` and `RadioButton.setChecked()` on individual radio buttons. Use `RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener()` (through code, not the xml layout) to listen to changes in a `RadioGroup`.

Comment: thanks for idea, i will try it and tell you result, just to make it clear i should change that in Onresume and OnPause methodes, could you help me with an example of code :)