# Multiple instances of an Android fragment issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having trouble fixing the following issue:

I am making a small quiz android app. I have a QuizActivity and a QuizFragment, I build a list of QuizFragments in the activity:

```
questionFragments = new ArrayList<>();
questionFragments.add(QuestionFragment.newInstance(new Question("Amai menne ...",
        new ArrayList<Answer>() {{
            add(new Answer("Frak", false));
            add(new Answer("Jas", true));
            add(new Answer("Bernadette", false));
        }})));

questionFragments.add(QuestionFragment.newInstance(new Question("Question 2",
        new ArrayList<Answer>() {{
            add(new Answer("Answer 1", false));
            add(new Answer("Answer 2", true));
        }})));
```

[image]

I have a method in the activity that replaces the current QuestionFragment:

```
private void showQuestion(int question) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_quiz_fl_question, questionFragments.get(question));
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Callback in the QuestionActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCorrectAnswerSelected() {
    showQuestion(currentQuestion + 1);
}
```

In my QuestionFragment I build the RadioGroup programmatically (OnCreateView):

```
radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getContext());
radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.fragment_question_tv_title);
radioGroup.setLayoutParams(lp);

for (Answer answer : question.getAnswers()) {
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
    radioButton.setText(answer.getAnswer());
    radioButton.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 30);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
}
```

I have a listener on the button of the fragment:

```
verifyAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int checkedRadioButtonId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        if (question.getAnswers().get(checkedRadioButtonId - 1).isCorrect()) {
            //Correct
            handleSuccess();
        } else {
            //Incorrect
            handleFailure();
        }
    }
});
```

Now this is where I am having an issue, when I answer the first question everything works as planned but when I answer my second question the app crashes. I was able to pinpoint the problem with the help of debugging.
I seems that the RadioGroup "remembers" the possible answers from the previous questions (in this case I selected the second option from the second question). You can see below that the selected radioButtonId is 5 but I only have 2 radio buttons:

[image]

I would appreciate any help! Source code: https://github.com/Jdruwe/ElineBirthday

Comment: Programatically building UI? Are you **sure** you're updating the variables that are causing the IndexOutOfBounds` error with the new fragment's content / size-bounds?

Comment: I pass a new quesion object when calling the newInstance method of the fragment if that is what you mean.

Comment: I meant **do you update significant variables, such as `checkedRadioButtonId` which may cause errors down the line if not propertly initialized at proper time?**

Comment: Not that I can see, do you mind checking the source code (it is really small): https://github.com/Jdruwe/ElineBirthday

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to do the following to get the index of the selected RadioButton ([How to get the selected index of a RadioGroup in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440259/how-to-get-the-selected-index-of-a-radiogroup-in-android?ref=driverlayer.com/web)) :

```
int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int idx = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```