# radiobutton in android doesn't work

Tags: java, android, radio-button

in this program I use radiobuttons. Currently I've some problems with the button number 2 (`button2`), in fact when it is pressed nothing happens!

When I press `button2` it should show the name of each radio button in "TextView"
(while `button1` is used to clear choosing radio buttons). 
Can anyone please help me or give me any kind of tips? Thanks.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;    

public class RadiobuttonActivity extends Activity {     

    Button      button1;
    Button      button2;
    TextView    textView1;
    RadioButton r1;
    RadioButton r2;
    RadioButton r3;     

    RadioGroup  radioGroup1;     

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r1);
        r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r2);
        r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.r3);     

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                radioGroup1.clearCheck();
                textView1.setText("AllUnChecked");     
            }
        });     

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int selectedid = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                switch (selectedid) {
                    case 0:
                        textView1.setText("Red");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        textView1.setText("Green");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        textView1.setText("Black");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

---

this is the main.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/r1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Red" />



            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/r2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Green" />



            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/r3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Black" />

        </RadioGroup>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AllUnchecked" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Witch radio button is ckecked?" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text View"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

and this is main.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Red" />



        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Green" />



        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Black" />

    </RadioGroup>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AllUnchecked" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Witch radio button is ckecked?" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text View"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Please show the XML layout.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code here. I suggest setting a breakpoint in your event listener and using the debugged in Android Studio to determine what is happening.

Comment: this is the main.xml :

Comment: @Alien_x You shouldn't post your additional code as answer. Instead you should click on edit and then add it.

Comment: Please edit your original question.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440259/how-to-get-the-selected-index-of-a-radiogroup-in-android)

Instead of use:

```
int selectedid = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Use this:

```
 int selectedid = radioGroup1.indexOfChild(findViewById(radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
```

Comment: Mark it by clicking on the flag in the left. Thanks